# Java how to calculate average of an arrayList that some elements removed randomly?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

I have an `arrayList<Integer>` and `arrayList<JLabel>`. Integer holds the moneys as integers and JLabel holds the same values as strings. I want to remove randomly elements from both labels. For example if 20TL(tl is currency) removed in JLabel i want to remove it in integer arrayList too. It's simple. But then i want to calculate average of remains money in ArrayList. Here is my another arrayList to shuffle 0 to 23 numbers. Therefore i remove the same element both IntList and JLabel list.

```
ArrayList<Integer> Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int n = 0; n<24; n++){
                Numbers.add(n);
            }
        Collections.shuffle(Numbers);
```

Then here is my both lists.

```
ArrayList<Integer> Money = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Money.add(1); Money.add(5); Money.add(10); Money.add(25); Money.add(50); Money.add(100); Money.add(500); Money.add(1000); Money.add(2000);
            Money.add(5000); Money.add(10000); Money.add(20000); Money.add(25000); Money.add(30000); Money.add(40000); Money.add(50000); Money.add(100000); Money.add(200000);
            Money.add(300000); Money.add(400000); Money.add(500000); Money.add(750000); Money.add(1000000); Money.add(2000000);

String[] para =new String[] {"1 TL","5 TL","10 TL","25 TL", "50 TL","100 TL","500 TL",//create an array for moneys
                "1.000 TL","2.000 TL","5.000 TL","10.000 TL","20.000 TL","25.000 TL",
                "30.000 TL","40.000 TL","50.000 TL","100.000 TL",
                "200.000 TL","300.000 TL","400.000 TL","500.000 TL","750.000 TL"
                ,"1.000.000 TL","2.000.000 TL"};
        ArrayList <JLabel> myLabel = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        for(int i=0; i < 12 ; i++){
            JLabel holder = new JLabel();
            holder.setText(para[i]);
            myLabel.add(holder);
            p2.add(holder);//add the label to the panel

        }

            for(int j=12; j<para.length; j++){
            JLabel holder2 = new JLabel();
            holder2.setText(para[j]);

            myLabel.add(holder2);
            p3.add(holder2);
        }
```

here is my removing style.this in actionListener method

```
  private int asd = 0;
/////   some code    
 myLabel.get(Numbers.get(asd)).setVisible(false);
 Money.remove(Numbers.get(asd));
```

When i try to remove money in intarraylist the calculation method does not work properly. Because for example if the Numbers array's first element is 5 then the 50 will be removed. And arrayList will be shrinked. After that when Numbers.get(asd) is equal to 23, there will not 23th element in int arraylist. Because its shrinked and has no such 23th element. I hope i can tell my problem well.

Ps: I've tried to use array instead of arraylist. But i can't calculate the average of lefts. Because array doesn't  shrink when some element be removed.

Comment: You look to be overly complicating matters. Why not use a `JList<Integer>`, fill it with a `DefaultListModel<Integer>` and deal with only one collection -- here the list model.

Comment: For better help, and in fact the best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: I'm sorry for mess. I try it. But i can't see the model. Please show me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a lot of changes to that code. For one, I would try to create one collection of values, so that I don't have to fiddle with making changes to parallel collections, since I know that this would reduce the chance of errors. For something like this, I'd use a `JList<Integer>` and populate its model, a `DefaultListModel<Integer>` with integers. I can then easily display this as a Turkish Lira using a NumberFormat currency instance that is set to the Turkish Locale. For example if I create my model like so:

```
// constants used to populate my model
private static final Integer[] VALUES = { 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000,
        20000, 25000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000,
        1000000, 2000000 };

// locale for Turkey used to get its currency
private Locale trLocale = new Locale("tr", "TR");
// currency number formatter for Turkish Lira
private NumberFormat tlFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(trLocale);

// my JList's model
private DefaultListModel<Integer> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
// create the JList with its model
private JList<Integer> jList = new JList<>(listModel);

// elsewhere in my constructor
    // populate my list model with the array values
    for (Integer value : VALUES) {
        listModel.addElement(value);
    }

    // set my JList's renderer to render the numbers as Turkish Lira
    jList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

    // add my list to a JScrollPane and set how many rows are visible
    jList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
```

The JList's cell renderer will change the value that it holds, here an Integer, to a String representation as Turkish Lira:

```
private class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        String textValue = tlFormat.format(value); // format the Integer to its currency String

        // pass it into the super's renderer
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, textValue, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }        
}
```

Then if later I can remove selected values from the list in a button's ActionListener and have it call a method that calculates the average of all items held in the list:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    List<Integer> selectedValues = jList.getSelectedValuesList();
    for (Integer selectedValue : selectedValues) {
        listModel.removeElement(selectedValue);
    }

    // method elsewhere that iterates through the listModel, calculates an average
    // and displays it
    calculateAndDisplayAverage();
}
```

It could look like so:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your great effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a Map: i.e. `HashMap<Integer, JLabel> money` . Which would guarantee that your two data-sets are in sync.

For the average, Java 8 streams are really handy:

`Collection<Integer> amounts = money.keySet();
 double average = (double) amounts.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum() / amounts.size()`

Comment: @M.Aktas: if his answer helps, do up-vote it by clicking on the up-arrow.

Comment: I can't do it. Because I don't have 15 reputation.